# mlflow / app engine error code 405 method not allowed, when using remote tracking server

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-405, mlflow

I have both mlflow client and server running (both version 1.22.0).
The tracking server is deployed using GCP app engine.

From the client I set the remote uri like this:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("https://mlflow-xxx.appspot.com/#/")
```

And then I just want to run the quickstart example:

```
import os
from random import random, randint
from mlflow import log_metric, log_param, log_artifacts

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Log a parameter (key-value pair)
    log_param("param1", randint(0, 100))

    # Log a metric; metrics can be updated throughout the run
    log_metric("foo", random())
    log_metric("foo", random() + 1)
    log_metric("foo", random() + 2)

    # Log an artifact (output file)
    if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
        os.makedirs("outputs")
    with open("outputs/test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("hello world!")
    log_artifacts("outputs")
```

However, I get 405 method not allowed error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlflow_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    log_param("param1", randint(0, 100))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 416, in log_param
    run_id = _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 1311, in _get_or_start_run
    return start_run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 289, in start_run
    active_run_obj = client.create_run(experiment_id=exp_id_for_run, tags=tags)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 265, in create_run
    return self._tracking_client.create_run(experiment_id, start_time, tags)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 108, in create_run
    tags=[RunTag(key, value) for (key, value) in tags.items()],
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 174, in create_run
    response_proto = self._call_endpoint(CreateRun, req_body)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/store/tracking/rest_store.py", line 60, in _call_endpoint
    return call_endpoint(self.get_host_creds(), endpoint, method, json_body, response_proto)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 229, in call_endpoint
    response = verify_rest_response(response, endpoint)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/utils/rest_utils.py", line 175, in verify_rest_response
    raise MlflowException("%s. Response body: '%s'" % (base_msg, response.text))
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/create failed with error code 405 != 200. Response body: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

Notes:

- If I omit the # char at the end, I get a 404 error (the requested URL was not found on this server)
- If I run a different method (for example, get_experiment, so a GET request instead of a POST) I get a different error

> mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to endpoint was
> successful but the response body was not in a valid JSON format

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?
Maybe I need to set the tracking_uri differently?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the exact same issue. Although my version are a little bit different. The tracking server runs on 1.20 but the code ran on 1.22. When downgrading the version for my code again to ~=1.21 in the requirements, it is resolved again.

So it is more of a workaround then a solution and I can't say whether it would work on 1.22 for both sides on my part, because I don't want to touch the seperate tracking server at the moment.

I guess it is just a temporary bug in the 1.22 version. It seems to be already adressed: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/5171

Either way, if you use 1.21 you aren't missing out on too much and run on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue in my case. I downgraded first the client to 1.21 and then also the server to 1.20... so to have your same versions. But the errors are still there.

Comment: Can you vouch for the exact versions? Running version on the MLFlows server cli command and running mlflow.__version__ in the client script?
Sorry for asking, but I experience this very often that version are set somewhere but the installation got a different turn, or in the end a wrong interpreter is called.
And I ran with Python3.9 by the way.